# How can one pass a date to CloudKit via CK Web Services from a PHP script?

Tags: php, date, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

I am writing a PHP script to send data to a CloudKit database via CK Web Services. It works well with string data, but I am having trouble passing a date from PHP to a CK Date/Time field.

CK returns dates as a 13-digit TIMESTAMP. So, the following code

```
$timestamp = $record['created']['timestamp'];
$timestamp = $timestamp/1000;
echo '<td>'.date('m-d-Y H:i:s', $timestamp)."</td>";
```

echoes out

> 04-28-2017 12:35:19

Fine and dandy.

So I make the assumption that if CK delivers a 13-digit TIMESTAMP it should accept the same when passed to a Date/Time field.

Alas, passing `$dobTimestamp` from the following

```
$dobTimestamp = strtotime($dob) * 1000;
```

Results in this `BAD_REQUEST` error

> Invalid value, expected type TIMESTAMP

When I go to the CK Dashboard and manually enter `$dob`, CK returns a value exactly equal to `$dobTimestamp` so I think passing `$dobTimestamp` should work . . . but it does not.

I cannot find out what I am supposed to do in Apple's docs. Does anyone know how to pass a date to a CK Date/Time field via Web Services? Hard to imagine there would not be a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddles, here's what works using PHP DateTime:

```
$openingDate = $_POST['openingDate']; // is mm/dd/yyyy
$closingDate = $_POST['closingDate'];
```

. . .

```
// Process Dates
$openingDateTime = new DateTime($openingDate, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));  // Create new DateTime object
$closingDateTime = new DateTime($closingDate, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

date_time_set($openingDateTime, 10, 00); // Set time for date object
date_time_set($closingDateTime, 17, 00); // Set time for date object

$oDate = (date_timestamp_get($openingDateTime)*1000);  // Get the TIMESTAMP from DateTiem object and convert to milliseconds
$cDate  = (date_timestamp_get($closingDateTime)*1000);
```

The JSON for the CK Query is simple:

. . .

```
"openingDate": {"value":'.$oDate.'}, 
"closingDate": {"value":'.$cDate.'},
```

Comment: As Peter already figured out, you must send value as microseconds (13 digits). And please pay attention to type of value that you send to CK! It must be type of int not string.